# How do I get javascript auto completion working in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express

How do I get the autocomplete to work with visual studio code? I'm expecting to get the "listen" suggestion when referring the app.

This is what I'm getting....

[image]

I'm expecting to get the below. Screenshot is of a friends visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: What options do you have when you type `app.li`? Do you have identical files including `node_modules` contents?